# Setting equal height for images in Bootstrap Carousel

Tags: image, bootstrap-4, height, carousel

I have a series of images nested in a Bootstrap carousel element:

```
<div class="carousel-inner" role = "listbox">
                    <div class="carousel-item active">
                        <img class="d-block w-100 img-fluid" src="images/fullpics/landscapes/Old Sheds Evandale (Acrylic).tiff" alt="First Mage">
                        <div class="carousel-caption d-none d-md-block">
                            <h5>First slide label</h5>
                            <p>Nulla vitae elit libero, a pharetra augue mollis interdum.</p>
                          </div>
                    </div>
```

My issue is the images are varying in height, causing the images to 'jump' up and down as they transition, but consistently at the correct width.
To get the same width on all images I had to set

```
> w-100
```

although I had already set the image to be responsive `img-fluid` which I had thought would set all images to w-100 without my having to add same.

My question is  how do I set the height of each image to be equal without adjusting the dimension of the image itself?

Edit: After adding height attribute to enclosing div the image is cut short at the bottom end;

```
<div class="carousel-inner" style="height:400px;" role = "listbox">
```

[image: Imge cut off]

Comment: To the div class="carousel-inner" add h-75 that will restrict your div class to a specific height.  This is a dirty hack but it should work. If adding h-75 doesn't work, apply inline style to div, style="height:300px;"

Comment: The style works but it clips off the bottom of images that are large, is there a way to resize to fit with a defined height?

Comment: Can you include a screenshot to show how is it now for better clarity?

Comment: Ok have edited the question with cut off image

Comment: You can give same value of height and width to all the images along with the style to the div and then check. Setting height and width to images will solve your clip off issue, and giving style to div will solve your unusual behavior of container.

Comment: That did it thanks

Comment: I am glad it helped.